# Is cytoscape js responsive

Tags: cytoscape.js

I looked at few [examples](http://js.cytoscape.org/#demos) for cytoscape js. All the examples looks non responsive. Does it have a capability to be responsive ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cytoscape fully supports desktop and touch devices, and you can use responsive CSS on the Cytoscape container element -- and the graph viewport will update as specified.

Comment: That helps. Thanks for quick reply !